# Audio Downloader from YouTube with youtube-dl and ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, batch-file, youtube-dl

I am trying to make an audio downloader with `youtube-dl` and `ffmpeg` which will:

> 1. Download the best format of audio available on YouTube
> 2. Embed thumbnail in the file.
> 3. Convert the file to mp3.
> 4. Delete everything from the folder except the converted mp3 file.

Below is the code I've come up with:

```
@echo off
cls
set /p playlist="Enter YouTube Link: " 
youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a] -i --write-thumbnail --embed-thumbnail -o "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" %playlist% --exec "ffmpeg -i {} -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 0 {}.mp3 && del {}"
```

The issues I've been facing with my code:

1. The converted file is not renamed correctly. It's named `Filename.m4a.mp3` where I want it to be named `Filename.mp3`
2. Video thumbnail is saved as `Filename.jpg` and youtube-dl creates a file named `cookies.txt`. Those are not deleted automatically.
3. Lastly, this error shows up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHYyw.png

> [swscaler @ 00000143e0a4ffc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
> [mp3 @ 00000143e09f0340] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
> Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2

I'd really appreciate it if you helped me fix those issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code which is currently doing everything I need it to do:

```bsh
@echo off
cls
set /p playlist="Enter YouTube Link: " 
youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a] --extract-audio --write-thumbnail --embed-thumbnail -o "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" %playlist% --exec "ffmpeg -i {} -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 0 {}.mp3 && del {}"
@For /R %%f in (*) Do (if not "%%~xf"==".mp3" Del "%%~f")
@For %%G In (*.m4a.mp3) Do @For %%H In ("%%~nG") Do @Ren "%%G" "%%~nH%%~xG"
```